# Angular cdkDrag with cdkDragHandle in the template doesn't connect

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, drag, angular-cdk, drop

Is there any way to connect `cdkDrag` element with `ng-template` where in that `ng-template` there is a `cdkDragHandle`?

I would like to drag element only by tag marked with `cdkDragHandle`.

Here is small stackblitz to show the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-admshu?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.html

Comment: The answer in the linked question sums it up pretty well - cdkDrag relies on initial structure, so if `cdkDragHandle` is not ancestor of `cdkDrag` it will not work. Your best bet is to have two templates - one for handle, other for contents, and wrap the template for handler in a div with `cdkDragHandle`.

Comment: @TotallyNewb I'm not sure if I follow :( Are you able to change my stackblitz a little and show it on example? I would be greateful.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-admshu-kxrutc